# c++ ofstream doesn't modify files. Even the tutorial examples

Tags: c++, fstream, ofstream

I am writing a program that needs to read from one file and write to another. Using `fstream`, I implemented the reading part, but the writing part didn't work no matter what I tried.

I tried the 'example programs' from all sorts of websites, but none of them worked. I tried changing things like `file.isOpen() == false` to `!file` and all that, but still nothing.

It doesn't matter if file exists or not, `ofstream` functions just don't seem to work.

From what I read, it seems to be a permissions issue? Besides that, I have no other clue. There are no errors or abnormal statuses reported. Everything before and after works fine while `ofstream` functions are just ignored.

I am using Visual Studio Code, windows 10. Snippet from w3schools I tried.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Create and open a text file
    ofstream MyFile("filename.txt");

    // Write to the file
    MyFile << "Files can be tricky, but it is fun enough!";

    // Close the file
    MyFile.close();
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code (though `MyFile.close();` is superfluous), must be permissions like you say.

Comment: *"There are no errors or abnormal statuses reported"* - that you never bothered to *check* for such errors or abnormal statuses isn't adding any credence to that stance. If that file fails to open, everything after the first line is. rubbish. And since you never checked the former, nor the actual io operation, for any success, I'm not surprised everything seems rosy.

Comment: @WhozCraig I comiled & run the program, checked the vscode workspace 'problems', 'output', 'terminal' which are the only tools I know exist, but there is nothing there.  Maybe I misunderstood you? And I don't know how to check io operation for any success.

Comment: @timebender `if (MyFile.is_open())` would check if the file has opened and `if (!(MyFile << "Files can be tricky, but it is fun enough!"))` would check if the output operation has failed (very little chance of that however).

Comment: `if (!MyFile.is_open()) { std::perror("filename.txt"); std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@timebender
I tried following code using g++.exe(cygwin windows)

```
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/errno.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
     // Create and open a text file
     ofstream MyFile("filename.txt", ios::app|ios::out);
     if ( MyFile.is_open() )
     {
            cout << "is_open pass\n";
            // Write to the file
            MyFile << "Files can be tricky, but it is fun enough!\n";
            // Close the file
            MyFile.close();
            cout << "closed file\n";
     }
     else
     {
            cout << "ofstream filename.txt failed\n";
            cout << strerror(errno) << "\n";
     }
     return 0;
    }
    $ g++ 73174678.cpp -o ./a.out;a.out
    $ ./a.out
    is_open pass
    closed file
    $ cat "filename.txt"
    Files can be tricky, but it is fun enough!
    $ g++.exe 73174678.cpp -o ./a.exe;./a.exe
    $ ./a.exe
    is_open pass
    closed file
```

```
I tried your updated program.<BR>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
        ofstream ofs;
        system( "echo Before;cat filename.txt");
        ofs.open("filename.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);
        ofs<<"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        ofs.close();
        system( "echo After;cat filename.txt");
        return 0;
}
Sample output:
$ a.exe
Before
Files can be tricky, but it is fun enough!
After
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa$ ./a.exe
Before
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAfter
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa$ a.exe
Before
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAfter
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Hence need your expected output here ?
I tried compiling your program using g++.exe at my local host.
```

Comment: I tried using the ios::app|ios::out and it worked. Whenever a file doesn't already exists, it works fine.  However, when it already exists, it reports: 'permission denied'. I want my program to function like this: a) If file doesn't exist -> create an empty file & b) If file already exists, overwrite it (all previous contents erased and only the new ones remain). How should I go about doing that?

Comment: nevermind, I found the ::trunc flag.

Comment: I found the ::trunc flag but I have an issue. It is at odds with ::app since one truncates and the other appends, so I tried removing it. When I don't have a ::app flag, it reports: 'permission denied' but when I do, it still doesn't work and it says: 'Ofstream filename.txt failed. No error'. Why is that?

Comment: instead of writing the comment, provide your updated code for me to test the same here.

Comment: ```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()    {
    std::ofstream ofs;
    ofs.open("filename.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);
    ofs<<"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    ofs.close();
     return 0;
}
```
And how did you do that? How do you follow program execution with it?

Comment: updated my comment. Let us know your expected output?